# Column visibility issue ag-grid-react, pinned columns not showing up on first render

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

We are using `"ag-grid-community": "26.2.0"` and `"ag-grid-react": "26.2.0"` packages in our project. We have implemented a wrapper reusable component which we're planning to use across the application.

The requirement states that checkbox selection and the first column are to be pinned to the left by default.

**Column Definitions:**

```
const colDefs = [
    {
      headerName: "Vulnerability Title",
      field: "patchName",
      cellRendererFramework: patchListRenderers.patchNameRenderer,
      pinned: "left", // pinned property
      minWidth: 300,
    },
    {
      headerName: "Status",
      field: "vulnerabilityStatus",
      minWidth: 180,
    },
    {
      headerName: "Vulnerability ID",
      field: "cveId",
      minWidth: 210,
    },
    // more column definitions here
]
```

**My gridOptions are this:**

```
export const gridProps = {
  reactUi: true,
  rowHeight: 70,
  headerHeight: 70,
  rowSelection: "multiple",
  suppressRowClickSelection: true,
  pagination: true,
  paginationPageSize: 10,
  suppressPaginationPanel: true,
  enableCellTextSelection: true,
  ensureDomOrder: true,
  suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns: true,
  suppressColumnVirtualisation: true,
  popupParent: document.querySelector("body"),
};
```

I am facing a weird issue where the pinned column headers are shown, but the data underneath is missing, however, once I drag around the pinned column a bit, everything comes back in its proper place. Please refer to the GIFs attached.

**Things I've tried:**

- Changed the `width` values,
- Tried true and false for `suppressColumnVirtualisation` property.
- Tried to use `gridApi.redrawRows()` and `gridApi.refreshCells()` on the `onGridReady` event.
  None of these suggestions worked.

[GIF 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEcNA.gif)
[GIF 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vI7H.gif)

Comment: How does it look without the custom cell renderer? I would suspect that.

Comment: @JosefBláha, it behaves in a similar fashion with or without the celRenderer. I tried to do a `griApi.sizeColumnsToFit()` on the `onGridReady` event as well. It seemed to solve my issue, but now I'm facing another issue where the cleckboxed are getting clipped midway.